# Css3 border только в углах и определенного размера

Tags: css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такие углы можно сделать средствами css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно поиграться с `background` и `linear-gradient`

```css
.border {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(0, red, red), linear-gradient(0, red, red),
    linear-gradient(0, red, red), linear-gradient(0, red, red);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-size: 20px 1px, 1px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border"></div>
```

Или использовать `border` у псевдоэлементов.

```css
.border {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 90px;
  position: relative;
}

.border::before,
.border::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.border::before {
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.border::after {
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="border"></div>
```